# Automapper - update existing instance

Tags: c#, automapper

I have these classes:

```
public class SourceA 
{
  public double SourceAProp { get; set; }
}

public class SourceB
{
  public double SourceBProp { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
  public double SourceAProp { get; set; }
  public double SourceBProp { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SourceA, Dest>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();            
var dest = mapper.Map<SourceA, Dest>(sourceA.Value);

config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SourceB, Dest>());
mapper = config.CreateMapper();            
dest = mapper.Map<SourceB, Dest>(sourceB.Value);
```

But I think `Map` creates instance on each execution.

How can I use AutoMapper to create a single `Dest` instance with both `SourceA` and `SourceB` instances values (or updating the created instance after first execution) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Map<...>()` method has an overload where you can supply the destination object. So it's basically

```
Dest dest = new Dest();
mapper.Map<SourceA, Dest>(sourceA.Value, dest);
//...
mapper.Map<SourceB, Dest>(sourceB.Value, dest);
```

Comment: Note that this overload only exists if you specify `<TSource, TDest>` - if you only specify `Map<TDest>(...)`, the overload is not present. [Refer to the source.](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/104a192407858fe3a54a8a937ca95a34fd7c6959/src/AutoMapper/Mapper.cs#L156)